# cygwin: "no such file or directory" when trying to install something

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I've installed 32 bit cygwin on a virtual machine running Win 7 32 bits.
Since I'm trying to install expect-lite there, during the installation I selected packages TCL and Expect. I did this before on a 64-bit Win 10 machine (a host, not a VM) and everything went on smoothly. But now I'm getting a "no such file or directory" error when running `./install setup.sh`.

This is what happens:

[image: cygwin screenshot]

These are the packages I have:

```
$ cygcheck -c
Cygwin Package Information
Package                               Version                      Status
_autorebase                           001005-1                     OK
adwaita-icon-theme                    3.22.0-1                     OK
adwaita-themes                        3.22.2-1                     OK
alternatives                          1.3.30c-10                   OK
base-cygwin                           3.8-1                        OK
base-files                            4.2-4                        OK
bash                                  4.4.12-3                     OK
binutils                              2.25-2                       OK
bzip2                                 1.0.6-3                      OK
ca-certificates                       2.11-1                       OK
coreutils                             8.26-2                       OK
csih                                  0.9.9-1                      OK
cygutils                              1.4.15-2                     OK
cygwin                                2.8.0-1                      OK
cygwin-devel                          2.8.0-1                      OK
damageproto                           1.2.1-1                      OK
dash                                  0.5.9.1-1                    OK
dbus                                  1.10.12-1                    OK
dbus-x11                              1.10.12-1                    OK
dejavu-fonts                          2.37-1                       OK
desktop-file-utils                    0.23-1                       OK
diffutils                             3.5-2                        OK
dri-drivers                           17.0.3-1                     OK
editrights                            1.03-1                       OK
expect                                5.45-3                       OK
file                                  5.25-1                       OK
findutils                             4.6.0-1                      OK
fixesproto                            5.0-1                        OK
gamin                                 0.1.10-15                    OK
gawk                                  4.1.4-3                      OK
gcc-core                              5.4.0-1                      OK
gcc-g++                               5.4.0-1                      OK
gdk-pixbuf2.0-svg                     2.40.16-1                    OK
getent                                2.18.90-4                    OK
gnome-menus                           3.13.3-3                     OK
grep                                  3.0-2                        OK
groff                                 1.22.3-1                     OK
gsettings-desktop-schemas             3.22.0-1                     OK
gtk-update-icon-cache                 3.22.10-1                    OK
gtk2.0-engines-pixmap                 2.24.31-1                    OK
gzip                                  1.8-1                        OK
hicolor-icon-theme                    0.15-1                       OK
hostname                              3.13-1                       OK
info                                  6.1-2                        OK
ipc-utils                             1.0-1                        OK
kbproto                               1.0.7-1                      OK
less                                  481-1                        OK
libargp                               20110921-3                   OK
libatk1.0_0                           2.22.0-1                     OK
libatomic1                            5.4.0-1                      OK
libattr1                              2.4.46-1                     OK
libautotrace3                         0.31.1-17                    OK
libblkid1                             2.25.2-2                     OK
libbz2-devel                          1.0.6-3                      OK
libbz2_1                              1.0.6-3                      OK
libcairo2                             1.14.8-1                     OK
libcdt5                               2.40.1-2                     OK
libcgraph6                            2.40.1-2                     OK
libcom_err2                           1.42.12-2                    OK
libcroco0.6_3                         0.6.11-1                     OK
libcrypt0                             1.4-1                        OK
libcurl4                              7.52.1-1                     OK
libdatrie1                            0.2.8-1                      OK
libdb4.8                              4.8.30-1                     OK
libdb5.3                              5.3.28-1                     OK
libdbus1_3                            1.10.12-1                    OK
libedit0                              20130712-1                   OK
libEGL1                               17.0.3-1                     OK
libEMF1                               1.0.8-1                      OK
libexif12                             0.6.21-1                     OK
libexpat-devel                        2.2.0-0                      OK
libexpat1                             2.2.0-0                      OK
libfam0                               0.1.10-15                    OK
libffi6                               3.2.1-1                      OK
libfftw3_3                            3.3.6-pl1-1                  OK
libfontconfig-common                  2.12.1-1                     OK
libfontconfig-devel                   2.12.1-1                     OK
libfontconfig1                        2.12.1-1                     OK
libfontenc1                           1.1.3-1                      OK
libfpx1                               1.3.1.4-1                    OK
libfreetype-devel                     2.6.5-1                      OK
libfreetype6                          2.6.5-1                      OK
libgc1                                7.2d-1                       OK
libgcc1                               5.4.0-1                      OK
libgd3                                2.2.4-1                      OK
libgdbm4                              1.12-1                       OK
libgdk_pixbuf2.0_0                    2.36.5-1                     OK
libgif4                               4.1.6-10                     OK
libGL-devel                           17.0.3-1                     OK
libGL1                                17.0.3-1                     OK
libglapi0                             17.0.3-1                     OK
libglib2.0_0                          2.50.3-1                     OK
libgmp10                              6.1.2-1                      OK
libgnome-menu3_0                      3.13.3-3                     OK
libgnutls28                           3.3.17-1                     OK
libgomp1                              5.4.0-1                      OK
libgraphite2_3                        1.3.8-1                      OK
libgs9                                9.19-1                       OK
libgssapi_krb5_2                      1.14.4-1                     OK
libgtk2.0_0                           2.24.31-1                    OK
libgts0.7_5                           20121130-1                   OK
libguile17                            1.8.8-3                      OK
libguile2.0_22                        2.0.14-1                     OK
libgvc6                               2.40.1-2                     OK
libharfbuzz0                          1.3.4-1                      OK
libhogweed2                           2.7.1-1                      OK
libICE6                               1.0.9-1                      OK
libiconv                              1.14-3                       OK
libiconv2                             1.14-3                       OK
libidn11                              1.29-1                       OK
libidn2_0                             0.11-1                       OK
libintl8                              0.19.8.1-2                   OK
libisl13                              0.14.1-1                     OK
libjasper1                            1.900.22-1                   OK
libjbig2                              2.0-14                       OK
libjpeg8                              1.5.0-1                      OK
libk5crypto3                          1.14.4-1                     OK
libkrb5_3                             1.14.4-1                     OK
libkrb5support0                       1.14.4-1                     OK
libLASi1                              1.1.1-2                      OK
liblcms2_2                            2.8-1                        OK
libllvm3.8                            3.8.1-1                      OK
libllvm3.9                            3.9.1-1                      OK
libltdl7                              2.4.6-4                      OK
liblzma5                              5.2.2-1                      OK
liblzo2_2                             2.08-1                       OK
libMagickC++6_6                       6.9.5.7-2                    OK
libMagickCore6_2                      6.9.5.7-2                    OK
libMagickWand6_2                      6.9.5.7-2                    OK
libmcpp0                              2.7.2-2                      OK
libming1                              0.4.7-2                      OK
libmpc3                               1.0.3-1                      OK
libmpfr4                              3.1.5-1p2                    OK
libncursesw10                         6.0-10.20170325              OK
libnettle4                            2.7.1-1                      OK
libnghttp2_14                         1.14.0-2                     OK
libnspr4                              4.13-1                       OK
libnss3                               3.27.1-1                     OK
libopenjp2_7                          2.1.2-1                      OK
libopenjpeg1                          1.5.2-3                      OK
libopenldap2_4_2                      2.4.42-1                     OK
libopenssl100                         1.0.2k-1                     OK
libp11-kit0                           0.22.1-1                     OK
libpango1.0_0                         1.40.4-1                     OK
libpaper-common                       1.1.24-2                     OK
libpaper1                             1.1.24-2                     OK
libpathplan4                          2.40.1-2                     OK
libpcre1                              8.40-2                       OK
libpipeline1                          1.4.0-1                      OK
libpixman1_0                          0.34.0-1                     OK
libplotter2                           2.6-5                        OK
libpng-devel                          1.6.28-1                     OK
libpng16                              1.6.28-1                     OK
libpng16-devel                        1.6.28-1                     OK
libpoppler-glib8                      0.52.0-1                     OK
libpoppler62                          0.45.0-2                     OK
libpoppler66                          0.52.0-1                     OK
libpopt-common                        1.16-2                       OK
libpopt0                              1.16-2                       OK
libpsl5                               0.17.0-1                     OK
libpstoedit0                          3.70-2                       OK
libquadmath0                          5.4.0-1                      OK
libreadline7                          7.0.3-3                      OK
librsvg2_2                            2.40.16-1                    OK
libsasl2_3                            2.1.26-9                     OK
libsigsegv2                           2.10-2                       OK
libSM6                                1.2.2-1                      OK
libsmartcols1                         2.25.2-2                     OK
libsqlite3_0                          3.16.2-1                     OK
libssh2_1                             1.7.0-1                      OK
libssp0                               5.4.0-1                      OK
libstdc++6                            5.4.0-1                      OK
libtasn1_6                            4.9-1                        OK
libthai0                              0.1.26-1                     OK
libtiff6                              4.0.6-1                      OK
libtxc_dxtn                           1.0-1.20151227gitf6ec862     OK
libunistring2                         0.9.6-1                      OK
libuuid1                              2.25.2-2                     OK
libvtv0                               5.4.0-1                      OK
libwebp5                              0.4.4-1                      OK
libWINGs3                             0.95.6-3                     OK
libwraster5                           0.95.6-3                     OK
libX11-devel                          1.6.4-1                      OK
libX11-xcb-devel                      1.6.4-1                      OK
libX11-xcb1                           1.6.4-1                      OK
libX11_6                              1.6.4-1                      OK
libxapian22                           1.2.24-1                     OK
libXau-devel                          1.0.8-1                      OK
libXau6                               1.0.8-1                      OK
libXaw7                               1.0.13-1                     OK
libxcb-composite0                     1.12-1                       OK
libxcb-devel                          1.12-1                       OK
libxcb-ewmh2                          0.4.1-1                      OK
libxcb-glx-devel                      1.12-1                       OK
libxcb-glx0                           1.12-1                       OK
libxcb-icccm4                         0.4.1-1                      OK
libxcb-image0                         0.3.9-1                      OK
libxcb-render0                        1.12-1                       OK
libxcb-shm0                           1.12-1                       OK
libxcb-util1                          0.3.9-1                      OK
libxcb1                               1.12-1                       OK
libXcomposite1                        0.4.3-1                      OK
libXcursor1                           1.1.14-1                     OK
libXdamage-devel                      1.1.4-1                      OK
libXdamage1                           1.1.4-1                      OK
libXdmcp-devel                        1.1.2-1                      OK
libXdmcp6                             1.1.2-1                      OK
libXext-devel                         1.3.3-1                      OK
libXext6                              1.3.3-1                      OK
libXfixes-devel                       5.0.3-1                      OK
libXfixes3                            5.0.3-1                      OK
libXfont1                             1.5.2-1                      OK
libXfont2_2                           2.0.1-1                      OK
libXft-devel                          2.3.2-1                      OK
libXft2                               2.3.2-1                      OK
libXi6                                1.7.8-1                      OK
libXinerama1                          1.1.3-1                      OK
libxkbfile1                           1.0.9-1                      OK
libxml2                               2.9.4-2                      OK
libXmu6                               1.1.2-1                      OK
libXmuu1                              1.1.2-1                      OK
libXpm4                               3.5.12-1                     OK
libXrandr2                            1.5.1-1                      OK
libXrender-devel                      0.9.9-1                      OK
libXrender1                           0.9.9-1                      OK
libXss-devel                          1.2.2-1                      OK
libXss1                               1.2.2-1                      OK
libXt6                                1.1.5-1                      OK
libzip2                               0.11.2-2                     OK
login                                 1.11-1                       OK
luit                                  20130217-1                   OK
make                                  4.2.1-2                      OK
man-db                                2.7.5-2                      OK
mcpp                                  2.7.2-2                      OK
mingw64-i686-binutils                 2.25.0.1.23f238d-1           OK
mingw64-i686-gcc-core                 5.4.0-4                      OK
mingw64-i686-gcc-g++                  5.4.0-4                      OK
mingw64-i686-headers                  5.0.2-1                      OK
mingw64-i686-runtime                  5.0.2-1                      OK
mingw64-i686-windows-default-manifest 6.4-1                        OK
mingw64-i686-winpthreads              5.0.2-1                      OK
mintty                                2.7.5-0                      OK
ncurses                               6.0-10.20170325              OK
openssl                               1.0.2k-1                     OK
p11-kit                               0.22.1-1                     OK
p11-kit-trust                         0.22.1-1                     OK
perl                                  5.22.3-1                     OK
perl_autorebase                       5.22.3-1                     OK
perl_base                             5.22.3-1                     OK
pkg-config                            0.29.1-1                     OK
poppler-data                          0.4.7-1                      OK
publicsuffix-list-dafsa               20170206-1                   OK
rebase                                4.4.2-1                      OK
renderproto                           0.11.1-1                     OK
run                                   1.3.4-2                      OK
scrnsaverproto                        1.2.2-2                      OK
sed                                   4.4-1                        OK
setxkbmap                             1.3.1-1                      OK
shared-mime-info                      1.7-1                        OK
tar                                   1.29-1                       OK
tcl                                   8.6.6-1                      OK
tcl-db                                5.3.28-1                     OK
tcl-db4.8                             4.8.30-1                     OK
tcl-devel                             8.6.6-1                      OK
tcl-itcl                              4.0.3-1                      OK
tcl-itcl-devel                        4.0.3-1                      OK
tcl-itk                               4.0.1-1                      OK
tcl-itk-devel                         4.0.1-1                      OK
tcl-iwidgets                          4.0.1-3                      OK
tcl-ming                              0.4.7-2                      OK
tcl-sqlite3                           3.16.2-1                     OK
tcl-tcldot                            2.40.1-2                     OK
tcl-tix                               8.4.3-3                      OK
tcl-tk                                8.6.6-1                      OK
tcl-tk-devel                          8.6.6-1                      OK
tcl-togl                              2.0-4                        OK
tcl-togl-devel                        2.0-4                        OK
tcl-xapian                            1.2.24-1                     OK
terminfo                              6.0-10.20170325              OK
tzcode                                2017a-1                      OK
tzdata                                2017b-1                      OK
util-linux                            2.25.2-2                     OK
vim-minimal                           8.0.0542-1                   OK
w32api-headers                        5.0.2-1                      OK
w32api-runtime                        5.0.2-1                      OK
wget                                  1.19.1-1                     OK
which                                 2.20-2                       OK
WindowMaker                           0.95.6-3                     OK
windows-default-manifest              6.4-1                        OK
xauth                                 1.0.9-1                      OK
xcursor-themes                        1.0.4-1                      OK
xdg-user-dirs                         0.15-1                       OK
xextproto                             7.3.0-1                      OK
xf86-video-dummy                      0.3.8-1                      OK
xf86-video-nested                     0.1.0-8.20160719git          OK
xinit                                 1.3.4-14                     OK
xkbcomp                               1.3.1-1                      OK
xkeyboard-config                      2.19-1                       OK
xmodmap                               1.0.9-1                      OK
xorg-server                           1.19.2-1                     OK
xorg-server-common                    1.19.2-1                     OK
xorg-x11-fonts-dpi75                  7.5-3                        OK
xorg-x11-fonts-misc                   7.5-3                        OK
xproto                                7.0.31-1                     OK
xrdb                                  1.1.0-1                      OK
xterm                                 327-1                        OK
xwin-xdg-menu                         20170321-1                   OK
xz                                    5.2.2-1                      OK
zlib-devel                            1.2.11-1                     OK
zlib0                                 1.2.11-1                     OK
```

Am I missing some package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PEBCAK :P
The command I was looking for was `./install.sh`. Now everything went ok.

Thanks for reading.